# Torsion and twist in solid cylindrical beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

Well given a beam (as shown), a solid cylinder with radius R. A Torque $T$ applied to it, I need to solve the angle of twist ($\theta$) at the position where the torque is applied ($z$).
[image]

The basic equation for torque is really simple:

$$T = GJ \frac{d\theta}{dz}$$
Where J is the polar moment of inertia.
$$J = \frac{\pi R^4}{4}$$

Now this could be "solved":
$$\frac{d\theta}{dz} = \frac{4T}{\pi GR^4}$$
$$\frac{\theta} = = \frac{4T}{\pi GR^4} z$$

However this would make the whole equation indepedent of where the torque is applied. And furthermore this would make it independent of fixture at edge of the beam (other edge). Shouldn't I need to get the internal torque moments, and use that for $T(z)$? (How?). Or is torque equal throughout the beam?

Comment: Hint:  Consider the cylindrical bar to be two torsional springs.

Comment: @Louis uh, what would that mean? I've never used such a method...

Answer (score 1):

When the torque is applied the shaft twists.  The twist gives rise to a reaction torque that opposes the applied torque.  This is analogous to a spring stretching when a force is applied.

When we integrate the differential equation along a *uniform* circular shaft of length $L$ we find that $T=-\frac{JG}{L}\theta$, which is analogous to $F=-kx$.  The minus sign indicates T is the restoring torque by the shaft, which is opposite to the applied torque.  The torsional stiffness of the shaft is $JG/L$.

We can treat each section of the shaft as a separate spring.  The twist $\theta_1$ in the spring on the left will give rise to a restoring torque $T_1$ and similarly for the shaft on the right.  For static equilibrium, $T+T_1+T_2=0$.  For physical continuity of the shaft, $\theta=\theta_1=\theta_2$.

A few things to be careful about when dealing with torsional shafts:  First, sometimes the shaft is not uniform.  It may have a sudden change in diameter or it may be tapered.  Second, the shafts are coupled through gears, which complicates the analysis. Third, when possible consider JG to be a single quantity.  The calculation will often be simpler and easier to check when the J and G are always together.  In other words, calculate the value a JG as a single value on the side and plug it into your formula in the end, if the shaft arrangement allows.

Fourth, here is a tip for how to remember the correct formula for the polar moment of inertia.  What I remember is there are two similar formulas.  One formula is for $I$, the moment of inertia used for circular beams in bending.  The other is the polar moment of inertial, used for circular shafts in torsion.  One formula is $\pi r^4/2$ and the other is $\pi r^4/4$.  The formula for the polar moment of inertia is like $A(x^2+y^2)$ and is twice as much as the other one which is just $Ax^2$ or $Ay^2$.  So, the polar moment must be the formula with the 2 in the denominator, because 1/4+1/4=1/2.  Or, if one uses diameters, one can remember the denominators are 32 and 64 and then it its easy to know which is used in bending and which in torsion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the step where:

$$\frac{d\theta}{dz}=\frac{4T}{\pi GR^4}$$

...becomes:

$$\theta=\frac{4T}{\pi GR^4} z+C$$

First, it is important to note that this step is only true if $T$, the internal torque, is constant. Second, note the constant $C$ which I added. The reason for both these things is that that step is actually obtained through integration:

$$\int d\theta = \frac{4}{\pi GR^4}\int T dz$$

Indeed, if $T$ is constant, you get the equation above. However, in your question, $T$ is not constant throughout the beam. It is true that, for regions of the beam with no external moment applied, that $T$ is constant throughout that region, so no net torque evolves, as displayed by the following thin free body diagram (Note that I use the convention of displaying the direction of torque using a straight arrow in the sense of the right hand rule):[image]

However, there exists a point along the cylinder at which an external torque is applied, and so the torque across the point is non-constant, and also discontinuous:
[image]

I have used $T_{ex}$ to mean the externally applied torque, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ to be the internal torques applied on the cut faces. To satisfy equilibrium, $T_2 = T_1 - T_{ex}$. Also, since nowhere else in the beam are external torques applied (except at fixtures, beware!), we can say the torque either side of the point of external torque is constant, and so the distribution of the internal torque along the beam may look like:
[image]

Note that $T_1$ and $T_2$ need to be determined using end conditions. Upon doing so, you can use the distribution of $T$ in the integration, to get you the correct answer.